# ListView items doesn't appear Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin

Good morning!
I've a big problem with ListViews in Xamarin Forms: my items aren't shown.

This is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         x:Class="KOTC.Views.News">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="list" HasUnevenRows="true" IsVisible="True">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid Padding="20">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Label Text ="{Binding title}" Grid.Row="0" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontSize="10" TextColor="Black"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding date}" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="10"/>

                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

and this is my class constructor:

```
 public News()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ObservableCollection<ListNewsItem> listNews = new ObservableCollection<ListNewsItem>();
        RemoteDBConnection conn = new RemoteDBConnection(QUERY);
        conn.Connect();
        List<Models.News> news = conn.ExecuteQueryWithResponse(QUERY);

        for (int i = 0; i < news.Count; i++)
        {

            ListNewsItem item = new ListNewsItem
            {
                date = news[i].publicationDate,
                title = news[i].title
            };

            listNews.Add(item);

        }

        list.ItemsSource = listNews;
    }
```

In this moment method ExecuteQueryWithResponse() returns 3 items, that are detected by ListView, in fact when I start the app, I see 3 ViewCells. The problem is that these viewcells are empty, they're not showing data.

Someone can help me?

Comment: if you hardcode a value in your Label does it display?  If it doesn't then you probably have a layout problem.  If it does, then you have a data problem and you should post your ListNewsItem class

Comment: omg, thank you! I've had a really stupid problem: I'didn't use getter and setter methods in my ListNewsItem class. Thank you so much for the answer!